# Text to speech in as3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, text-to-speech

I am looking for a text to speech component that i can use with as3/flex .

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an example of how to do this on my blog:
http://www.jamesward.com/2009/10/01/text-to-speech-in-flex/

Answer (score 6):

I ported a HMM based TTS engine to Flash using the Alchemy compiler. Demos, explanation and code are here:

http://www.edobashira.com/2010/01/flitehts-engine-for-flash-hmm-speech_22.html 
http://www.furui.cs.titech.ac.jp/~dixonp/hts/

Comment: This is real good example of client-side synthesis. I would give +100 if I could.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you mean to do it on the web or on the desktop. In fact, I didn't even know you could do it on the web until I saw James' reply up above.

I had done a TTS desktop application in Flash embedding the Flash ActiveX inside a C# application. The Flash movie sent a message to the shell using the ExternalInterface API, which in turn passed it on to a TTS ActiveX. I can't recall the name of the ActiveX we used, but there are several decent options to choose from. Turned out quite sweet.